# How to copy the format and values without copying the CF rules from a Conditional Formatted cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I try copying the data from excel and send via e-mail automatically. everything working fine except CF. '

I apply the below code but its coping the conditional format rules also, because of that the format getting changed at the time it pasted in outlook. Kindly help us to fix this issue.

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook


TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
rng.Copy

Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)



   .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
   .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
   .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
   .Cells(1).Select


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
```

End Function

Comment: Why not just remove the **xlPasteFormats** line of code??

Comment: If I removed the xlPasteFormats it will not paste the existing formats also like borders background color etc....

Comment: One way to remove any conditional aspects of the formatting is to first paste the range to Word and then from Word to Outlook.

Comment: Can you please share a sample code for the same?

Comment: See my post....................

Answer (score 1):

In this small example, we start with a small block of cells having Conditional Formatting.  The macro:

1. opens Word
2. creates a new doc
3. copies the table and pastes it into the doc
4. saves the doc
5. closes both the doc and Word

Put this in a standard module.  The resulting Word table should be formatted like the Excel table but with no "conditions"

```
Sub UsingWord()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
    Range("A1:B2").Copy
    With wrdDoc
        wrdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
        .SaveAs ("C:\TestFolder\tdoc.docx")
        .Close
    End With
    wrdApp.Quit
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Choose your own file and folder names.

**You must include a reference to the Word Object Model in your VBA > Tools > References**

Comment: Can you please let me know how to copy this data from word to outlook for sending mail?

Comment: @Deva Sorry...........that is something I do not know......I only use web-based email.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting is considered formatting, so the xlPasteFormats is why it is pasting the CF. I would try applying

```
.Cells(1).FormatConditions.Delete
```

after you have copied the value, and right before you start the paste option.

Comment: If I applied this it’s deleting entire formatting result like font color, background etc... But I don’t want to remove that. I need to remove only CF rules.

Comment: I went back and realized it has to be inserted after the paste and you do not need to use the PasteSpecial at all Here is an example `Range("A6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete`

Comment: No, it’s not working. And also I need to delete the CF rule before pasting.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include all of the code. It may be easier to see where the issue lies? Also, are you certain that the field where you are copying the data from has formatting other than what the CF applies?

Comment: When I add `Cells.FormatConditions.Delete` in between the two With..End With statements everything works for me.